# Salto de linea de un segundo textview android

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, textview

Tengo dos *textview* en una misma linea, los dos textview no tienen contenido estático, el problema viene cuando *el segundo textview* se carga con los datos, este toma la segunda linea pero no desde la izquierda completamente.
Espero puedan ayudarme.

El **código** es éste:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/add"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="uno"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:textSize="@dimen/msg_text_primary"
                android:textColor="@color/from"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_titulo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="titulo"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:textSize="@dimen/msg_text_primary"
                android:textColor="@color/from"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/add"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/add"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/add"
               />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

**La imágen:**
[image: imagen]

---

Este en el código que tengo con los dos textview

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/add"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="uno"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:textSize="@dimen/msg_text_primary"
                android:textColor="@color/from"
                android:maxLines="1"
              />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_titulo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="titulo"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/msg_text_primary"
                    android:textColor="@color/from"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT**

Deseo hacer lo reflejado en la imagen de abajo, tengo dos valores el nombre y la descripcion lo que hago es setearlo en dos textview, intento lograr el comportamiento de la imagen abajo reflejada..

informacion adicional lo reflejado en negrita es un textview, y el comentario es otro textview.. agradezco la ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: alguien me ayuda?

Comment: Puedes poner el segundo Textview debajo del primero. Cuando escribas algo en el primer textview en negrita, en el segundo escribes el mismo número de espacios que caracteres tiene lo escrito en el primero y después añades el comentario. No es muy elegante pero creo que es una manera sencilla de hacerlo y así te quedará con el mismo formato

Comment: Porque utilizar 2 textviews? Podrias perfectamente utilizar 1 solo

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción sería utilizar el método spannable, en el cual solo ocupas un textView, ejemplo:
obtienes 2 strings (uno y dos) y "formateas" los strings así:

```
final SpannableString text = new SpannableString(uno);
final SpannableString text2 = new SpannableString(dos);
text.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, uno.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);        // texto en bold           
text.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 0, uno.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);   // texto color negro
text.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), 0, uno.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);   // tamaño 1.5f
text2.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), 0, dos.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);   // en italica
textView1.setText(TextUtils.concat(text," " ,text2));           // se concatena con text utils
```

Answer (score 0):

Una opción sencilla es usar un `LinearLayout` con orientación vertical:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="uno"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:textSize="@dimen/msg_text_primary"
    android:textColor="@color/from"
    android:maxLines="1" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_titulo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="titulo"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:textSize="@dimen/msg_text_primary"
    android:textColor="@color/from"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    />
```

si usas un RelativeLayout, te aconsejo revisar el funcionamiento de las siguientes propiedades que esas usando inadecuadamente.

```
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" 
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/add"
```

Comment: amigo ya lo intente con un linear layout. y no tengo el comportamiento desdeado, pues le comento que deseo hacer es un nombre de usuario y un comentario todo en una misma linea pero el problema viene cuando el segundo textview  del comentario no continua todo hasta la izquierda queda el espacio del textview del titulo

Comment: Tal vez hay  algo que no entendí, deseas que el segundo TextView este abajo e inicie su texto a la izquierda como el primero?

Comment: gracias por responder este alado del primer textview